# SourceSets in build.gradle - > Task :buildSrc:compileJava NO-SOURCE

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to build my Java project. Right now I am getting only this message: `Task :buildSrc:compileJava NO-SOURCE`
Do I need to modify sourceSets in `build.gradle` to make it run? What do I have to change? Thanks!
A piece of my `build.gradle` file:

```
sourceSets {
    //needed to run in intellij
    local {

    }

    main {
        resources {
            srcDir "src/main/markets"
        }
    }

    coreTest {
        java {
            srcDir file('src/test-core/java')
        }
        resources.srcDir file('src/test-core/resources')
    }

    componentTest {
        java {
            srcDir file('src/test-component/java')
        }
        resources.srcDir file('src/test-component/resources')
    }

    integrationTest {
        java {
            srcDir file('src/test-integration/java')
        }
        resources.srcDir file('src/test-integration/resources')
    }

    //needed to run in intellij
    util {
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like something you would put in a `buildSrc` project. Are you sure you are not mixing them up?